# How can I use a SOQL query to get the number of AccountTeamMembers on an account?

Tags: soql, query, account, account-teams

I can write something like this to give me the AccountTeamMembers on all accounts

```
select Id, (SELECT Id, AccountId FROM AccountTeamMembers) From Account
```

but I don't know how to just get the count of AccountTeamMembers on the account, as you can't use `COUNT` in the inner query. I'm ultimately trying to find accounts where there is more than one AccountTeamMember on the Account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to Aggregate SOQL to do that. You can't filter a parent query based upon a child subquery. You can, however, filter based on a grouping in a child query.

```
SELECT count(Id), AccountId 
FROM AccountTeamMember 
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING count(Id) > 1
```

Here, we go to the `AccountTeamMember` level, group by `AccountId`, and then select the `AccountId` for those groupings of child records that meet our requirements.

For more, see the SOQL and SOSL Reference under [`GROUP BY`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) and [`HAVING`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm), as well as [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into `HAVING` but was going about it backwards by trying to use the Account. I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Queries for related data on a parent record (up the heirarchy, say from `Opportunity` to `Account`) are represented as an `SObject` instance.

Likewise, for related data on child records (down the hierarchy, like from `Account` to `AccountTeamMembers`, always appearing in an inner query), the data is represented as a `List<SObject>`.

So `Account.AccountTeamMembers` is a `List<SObject>`, and the list class provides a size method. That's a way to get the count you're looking for.

The big caveat here is that there is a not very-well defined point, after which you can't do anything with your child object list other than iterate over it. Best guess is that it's related to calls to queryMore.

The following is the safest (but not the fastest) way to count child records if you're stuck using a parent-child subquery.

```
Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>> accountIdToTeamMembers = new Map<Id, List<AccountTeamMember>>();

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, AccountId FROM AccountTeamMembers) FROM Account]){
    accountIdToTeamMembers.put(acct.Id, new List<AccountTeamMember>());

    for(AccountTeamMember atm :acct.AccountTeamMembers){
        accountIdToTeamMembers.get(acct.Id).add(atm);
    }

    system.debug(accountIdToTeamMembers.get(acct.Id).size());
}
```